# Variable on ASPX page is inaccessible due to its protection level from code behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to fix up a old project and getting error :

> ProductionSchedule.aspx.vb(72,0): error BC30451: 'PanelStatusBL' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Now on ASPX page it's simple :

```
<%@ Page Title="Production Schedule" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"   
AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ProductionSchedule.aspx.vb" Inherits="ProductionSchedule" %>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelStatusBL" runat ="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID">                          
                            <div style="width:100%; text-align:left">  
                                <h5><asp:Label ID="LabelBatchLineHeading"  
 runat="server" Text="Status - Batch Line 1"></asp:Label></h5>                                    
</div>
```

What could be the issue?

There are other variables(controls) on this page which have same issue.

Comment: These type of errors comes due to declare private class. Please check in code behind. ( if possible please share).

Comment: I am getting this error in code behind and the control is on aspx page. Code behind is having difficulties to reach aspx (view)

Comment: Share code from code-behind file. Better to post complete code.

Answer (score 0):

It's that the entire .aspx code? If not, it could be that you have your control in an UpdatePanel or something like that?

In that case I would wrap the panel inside a

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"> ... </div>
```

and try to get the panel like this:

```
myDiv.FindControl("PanelStatusBL")
```

If that's the entire relevant .aspx code I'd told you to clean the solution and build it again